# Adding constraints is DDL or DML

Tags: sql-server, constraints, ddl, dml

Adding constraints in sql server comes under which category DML or DDL?

Comment: Please state your question more fully. Including commas in the right places would help understanding it.

Answer (score 3):

DDL, as you're *defining* the relationships between tables, not *modifying* the data stored in them.

Answer (score 2):

DDL, since they alter the structure rather than the data.

For example: [Referential integrity statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language#Referential_integrity_statements)

Answer (score 0):

Constraints must be **DDL** statements.Let's prove it.
Create two tables **A** and **B** as follows:

**create table A ( id int primary key );**

**create table B ( id int, foreign key id references A(id) );**

Now, let's try to insert some data in table A, and then table B.

**INSERT into A values (1);**

**INSERT into B values (1);**

Now, try to run **TRUNCATE A**;
It will give **Foreign Key Constraint Fail** error. It means that Constraints are applied on **schema** of tables, hence **DDL statements**.